# Home screen web app clipped from bottom

Tags: ios, css, jquery-mobile, ios8

I am building a mobile app with jQuery Mobile for iPad landscape orientation. The pages are 1024px to 768px. When I view it on the desktop (Chorome, Safari, Firefox) it is rendering as it should (1024x768).

But after I save it to the Home Screen on the iPad (iOS 8) and open it, the pages are rendered as trimmed (around 20px) from the bottom. When I check it from the inspector, i see that the `html` element (which is assigned 99.9% height) is rendering as 747px height. So is the `body` element.

I tried to give pixel values as height, margins, paddings and all but some greater container seems to be clipping them.

I also tried a few things with the `@viewport` rule but nothing came out of it.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was about the status bar. In the default mode, the iOS will pull all your html under the status bar but size the viewport to leave space for the bar (`height: 748px`). So the space below the 748px will be left blank, to show the white background.

When I added the line below in the head of my html file, the problem was solved (the viewport height equal to 768px -landscape)

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

I then tried it with different values for the content attribute, first with `content="black"`, and then with `content="default"`. In the latter it was the same as no meta tag was applied. With `content="black"`, the bottom was again left blank, but this time the the background color was *black*.